# Inconsistent behaviour when using `never` to make a field non-optional when another is passed

Tags: typescript, types

I need to describe an entity that can have either `text` property or `text`, `color` and optionally `icon`. For such entity I wrote the following type

```
type Entity =
  | { text: string; color?: never; icon?: never }
  | { text: string; color: string; icon?: string }
```

When defining an `Entity[]`, I get the results I would expect

```
const entities: Entity[] = [
  // ok
  { text: 'foo' },
  { text: 'foo', color: 'red' },
  { text: 'foo', color: 'red', icon: 'apple' },

  // error ~ 'color' is missing
  { text: 'foo',  icon: 'apple' },
]
```

However, I get different results when `Entity` is returned by functions

```
type EntityFn = 
  | (() => { text: string; color?: never; icon?: never })
  | (() => { text: string; color: string; icon?: string })

const entityFns: EntityFn[] = [
  // ok
  () => ({ text: 'foo' }),
  () => ({ text: 'foo', color: 'red' }),
  () => ({ text: 'foo', color: 'red', icon: 'apple' }),

  // I would expect an error here, but the compiler does not complain
  () => ({ text: 'foo', icon: 'apple' }),
]
```

In addition, when appending an unassignable function to `entityFns`, eg. `() => ({ nonexistent: true })` the compiler starts complaining about `() => ({ text: 'foo', icon: 'apple' })` is missing `color`.

I checked TypeScript FAQ and docs, but I've not been able to wrap my head around this. Can you help me understand why this happens?

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqKBeAUFLUA+UDeUwEAHsAFxQDOwATonAOYDcUAxgPYA2HtA-JTgQAbhFqtEnOAKhDRtKAF9M2PIWJlKNek1acetLXQYsokjtKM7GS9Oik0oEBMkQQqleElABtALpoUD4qWAD0oVAcANYhBESkFFAA5ABmHBxJSgA0seoJlKnpSVns3LwFtBAAJpmKOdhxGomFGSX65cmVNSXmcAUAhmBgXBC1ObHhTrS0vFAAfslUImLIIJmIVFAAthtUJrnxmslprWZSA0MjY+h+dqCQsC6gAGJwaLF4ABSfAJRoAHyNfLUYy6UoGGRyMQSKSQ5YKRQ-D5Qb5-VCAvJHbQmPRlQwg6wwiwybFMJRI+wWRzObwgV4eR6017+QLBBqTaKxX4AlGY5onWo-erYbno3mHflFNp4irVQXCrCiwGfPkFAXSgyy7pnCwXYajcnjdkRACSUAA7hwAK5cKpOEiQNjAKD9N5iGYKAAWYggJQARlbncBvaUtmBECMFFUOO5ZBxnZww1x+gwuWjlarjlKdX1koN9fK7MaoAAhEBQK1wRNbGkmIghtJcHjmkwlYPQMCVYSIa2bFKVp09t4tptQWgppYut3TXgTCJK8VwCykDbEBCUOhW6CIm7oIA)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a linter issue, something that has to do with a wrong "priority" on type checks.

Editing your code like this (by removing the first rule of the custom type), the expected error will appear:

```js
type EntityFn = (() => { text: string; color: string; icon?: string });

const entityFns: EntityFn[] = [
    // obviously in error in this case
    () => ({ text: 'foo' }),

    // ok
    () => ({ text: 'foo', color: 'red' }),
    () => ({ text: 'foo', color: 'red', icon: 'apple' }),

    // error, as expected
    () => ({ text: 'foo', icon: 'apple' }),
]
```

As we can see, the more restrictive rule (alone) seems to be working when used as return type in function but, when using also the other rule `{ text: string; color?: never; icon?: never }`, the linter seems to stop at the first case, in particular at the optional (`?`) rule.

This makes sense also because in the case of `{ text: string; color?: never; icon?: never }`, fields `color` and `icon` are not excluded at the same time, they're just optional one by one.

A possible workaround is to use `satisfies` on function results:

```js
const entityFns: EntityFn[] = [
    // ok
    () => ({ text: 'foo' } satisfies Entity),
    () => ({ text: 'foo', color: 'red' } satisfies Entity),
    () => ({ text: 'foo', color: 'red', icon: 'apple' } satisfies Entity),

    // error
    () => ({ text: 'foo', icon: 'apple' } satisfies Entity),
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this does not explain why the original `EntityFn` works as expected with plain objects though. The more restrictive rule should read "include `text` property only", I'm not sure I understand why the behaviour would make sense. If it is a linter issue, I should probably open an issue in TS github repo.